# Run a command in background that sets env var or define function

Tags: bash, process, environment-variables, autocomplete

```
> export foo=1 &
[1] 9016
[1] + done      export foo=1
> echo $foo

>
```

I know when running a command with `&` you spawn a new process and the `export foo=1` is not setting env vars in the parent shell. However, is this doable?

Spefically, I'm developing on Node and a lot of packages like running js commands and setup completion on the fly, for example grunt and gulp. That's too slow.

I'm thinking about making a utility similar to [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv). When you enter a dir, it runs the js commands and setup completion in the background, and reruns when `Gruntfile.js` or `gulpfile.js` changes, etc.

So, how can I run a command asychronously, and when it ends, defines env vars & functions for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By strict interpretation what you want to do is impossible. So the question is how much do you have to cheat to pull something like this off? You need bash, a PROMPT_COMMAND and two temporary files. you will also have to accept that the shell will not be updated until the command after completion of the background task. I would also recommend using make in the background process so the lengthy task is only run as needed.

First setup your event hook:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ -e file2 ]] && { . file2; rm file2 }'
```

then fire off the background process

```
(echo export foo=1 > file1 && mv file1 file2 )&
```

Why the `mv`? The presence of file2 indicates that the task is complete and that the file can be parsed, so you can take your sweet time building file1.

Comment: I wouldn't say this hack is really elegant, but your answer inspired me: in the case of zsh, maybe I could add a precmd hook that checks the presence of a text file and source its definition. OTOH, I'll use `autoenv` or something else to generate that text file to be sourced. Thanks!